# vi text search with exclude (linux)

Tags: linux, search, text, vi

I have a huge log file (25.3 million lines) with errors and I won't to search it without holding down the up button. How can you search this with vi? I've seen similar at directory levels but not particular files. At the moment I've searched a date e.g. /Tue 15 Jan
and navigated down but I'm not sure when problems may have began (only when noticed) so I need a general search.

My general idea from within the file would be /ORA-/!ORA-00020
meaning that I want to find those strings containing "ORA-" but ignoring those that are "ORA-00020". Any idea how this can be done viewing a particular file?

Thanks for any info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do

```
 grep -v "ORA\-00020" error.log > error2.log
```

then you search error2.log

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted but does the job. Luckily there is other drives to move the new 1gb text file to since the directory with the 2 together had 90% space used.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exactly way on vi, but we have kind of ways to get the result:

1. we can use cat/grep commands and write the answers in another file (so we have much smaller file) and then you can search in it, if it will be ok.
2. you can use vim instead vi and use TagList Vim Plugin.

Additional info at:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/04/ctags-taglist-vi-vim-editor-as-sourece-code-browser/

http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/faq.html